# How to keep test cases synced with HP ALM after refactoring?

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, quality-center, testng

We're planning to automate test synchronization between HP ALM QC and our TestNG test cases. We want to keep them synced in the following scenarios:

- *Test adding*: When creating TestNG test, a test should be created in HP QC
- *Test execution*: When executing TestNG test, a test instance with status should be created in HP QC
- *Refactoring*: Name and directory of TestNG test should correspond to name and directory of the test in HP QC. So when refactoring a Java class test (i.e., renaming a class or moving between packages),

So we were thinking about different approaches, each having some tradeoff

- **Approach #1**: Each time a dev creates a new test, calls maven plugin to add a test to HP QC and then add `@QCTestId` annotation with testId to the test class source code. Then it commits the class. Each time a dev updates a test name/package, it runs the plugin again to update test name/package in ALM.
- **Approach #2**: Similar as 1st approach, but the plugin does not update the test class source code, but adds this information to some external file/DB. When a test name/package is changed, the test with the old name is removed by the plugin from HP QC and added with a new name to HP QC.

Approach #1 looks a bit smelly to me because maven plugin is manipulating existing source code. While approach #2 has a limitation that by deleting the old test, we’re loosing also the history of test execution from HP QC.

Any other idea?